# Why is this code using VMULPD to write registers that will be overwritten by VFMADD? Isn't that useless?

Tags: assembly, avx, fma

While reviewing [this](https://github.com/tfhe/tfhe/blob/master/src/libtfhe/fft_processors/spqlios/lagrangehalfc_impl_fma.s#L29-L48) piece of code, I noticed the following four instructions:

```
vmulpd  %ymm1,%ymm3,%ymm4 /* aim*bim */
vmulpd  %ymm0,%ymm3,%ymm6 /* are*bim */
vfmadd231pd %ymm2,%ymm1,%ymm6
vfmsub231pd %ymm0,%ymm2,%ymm4
```

Now, if you consider that in AT&T notation the instructions are in the form `operator source,source,destination`, aren't the first instructions useless?

```
%ymm4 = f(%ymm1, %ymm3)
%ymm6 = f(%ymm0, %ymm3)
%ymm6 = f(%ymm2, %ymm1)
%ymm4 = f(%ymm0, %ymm2)
```

The first two values are clearly never read, so they shouldn't be calculated. However, it seems that this is not the case, since tests fail if I remove these lines.

Comment: The operand order is different for vfmadd and vfmsub. Check the manuals for details.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/4f/5b/36945), FMA instructions treat all three operands as sources (which makes sense, given the definition of FMA).

Comment: @fuz, according to an online manual, both [`VMULPD`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULPD.html) and [`VFMADD231PD`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VFMADD132PD:VFMADD213PD:VFMADD231PD.html) use the syntax `operator dst,src,src`. In that case, wouldn't the *second* instruction be useless, since it writes data that is never read from?

Answer (score 7):

**FMA is a 3-input instruction**, computing `a * b + c`; The destination is a read-write operand (like with SSE2 `mulpd %xmm0, %xmm1`).

FMADD/FMSUB/FNMADD/FNMSUB (and even FMADDSUB / FMSUBADD) instructions each come in 3 operand-orders to give you a choice of which of the 3 operands (a, b, or c) is the read-write destination operand, and which one can be a memory operand.  See [the docs for `vfmadd231pd`/ `132PD` / `213PD`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VFMADD132PD_VFMADD213PD_VFMADD231PD) to see which inputs are multiplied and which is the "accumulator" in your code.  (I can never keep the numbering scheme straight in my head: this is one case where writing with intrinsics is much easier.  But the destination is still always last.)

Note that the Intel docs use Intel syntax, `dst, src1, src2, ...`.  Reverse the list of operands to get AT&T syntax, e.g. `..., src2, src1, dst`.  See [the at&t-syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info), and also [the intel-syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info).

---

BTW, there is an FMA4 ISA-extension, where FMA instructions have 3 inputs and a *separate* output.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set.

Intel was originally going to implement FMA4, but then changed to the current FMA3 (without telling AMD until as late as possible, for anti-competitive reasons: See Agner Fog's blog post [Stop the instruction set war](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25)).  For AMD Bulldozer, it was too late to change, so Bulldozer only supports FMA4.  Piledriver supports FMA3 and FMA4.  Ryzen unofficially supports both until Zen 2.  Intel CPUs have only ever supported FMA3.

Ryzen Zen1 / Zen+ chips do apparently decode and execute FMA4 instructions correctly, but don't report FMA4 support in CPUID.  (There was [one sketchy report of incorrect FMA4 results, but nobody else reproduced it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739456/why-is-this-code-using-vmulpd-to-write-registers-that-will-be-overwritten-by-vfm/47739755?noredirect=1#comment82529280_47739755).  It seems to be just FUD rumours that circulated based on that one report, probably a software bug not a chip problem.)

However, **Zen 2 does *not* support FMA4**; illegal instruction (`#UD`) exception.

Comment: What are the "occasional wrong results" that you're referring to? FMA4 seems to work correctly for me on Ryzen as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Mysticial: [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set#cite_note-16) FMA article links to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/68s4bj/ryzen_has_undocumented_support_for_fma4/dh0y353/) as a source for FMA4 occasionally *not* giving correct results on Ryzen.  IDK if there's any better-documented evidence of a problem, or specific inputs that repro the problem.

Comment: Oh that one. I've seen it before and I don't think it's very credible given that no one else has hit it. While this doesn't explain that case (with incorrect results), it's common for FMA4 and XOP to be used together. So even though Ryzen supports FMA4, it'll still crash on XOP.

Comment: @Mysticial: I definitely remember reading this "fact", but maybe it all stemmed from that one sketchy report, e.g. maybe repeated in someone else's SO answer or comment.  Or maybe I read Wiki without checking the source for that claim!  Definitely sounds like "some guy who did something wrong or had bad hardware".  Or maybe the FMA4 results themselves weren't even wrong, just compiling for FMA4 vs. FMA3 led to different code-gen... deterministic FP is hard.  I was surprised that my search didn't turn up anything more solid than that; time to revise my mental database of facts.

Comment: I actually did go and trace back all the reports of this. They all ended up back to this same one. So it's just the same thing feeding itself. More likely, the problem is on the software side. Either (as you said), the compiler moved a few things around, or some sort of UB that got exposed.